# Docker container error: TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xffffffff, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to run a docker container from [microsoft/mssql-server-linux](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)

```
sudo docker run -d -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=SecertP@ssW0rd!' -p 1433:1433 --name TestName-SqlServer microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

The container does not start and when I  inspcts the logs:

```
docker logs e2
```

I see following errors:

> 2018-10-16 09:06:42.54 spid19s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2018-10-16 09:06:42.54 spid19s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xffffffff, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support.
>
> 2018-10-16 09:06:42.55 spid19s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2018-10-16 09:06:42.55 spid19s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xffffffff, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors.
>
> 2018-10-16 09:06:42.56 spid19s     Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
>
> 2018-10-16 09:06:42.56 spid19s     Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
>
> 2018-10-16 09:06:42.56 spid19s     Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2018-10-16 09:06:42.56 spid19s     SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the operating system error log for information about possible related problems.